# LBA48 PCI SATA controller card to use +137GB drives

Tags: hard-drive, pci

I currently have in my possession an old tower with an Asus motherboard that only has lba28. I want to use larger drives than is supported by lba28 (much larger).

Can I use an LBA48 PCI hard drive controller card to make use of drives larger than 137GBs on this old machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the controller will hold the LBA48 and work perfectly. This was a common solution about the time drives larger than 137GB became affordable and popular.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure I wasn't about to go and waste money on this, and through all my searching could never find any source that stated that this was possible